# Any idea to read user input as if it was code?

Tags: c++, string, input

I'm trying to make a boolean matrix calculator with the main operations: '^','v','*'. I already made it so you can fill it by asking for input for each box of the matrices. But it gets tedious when you are trying to fill a 10x10 matrix. So i wanted to have an option where you can fill by conditions (say i=row and j=column).

I want the user to be able to enter their own filling options. Like:

```
if (5 <= 3i+2j <=8)
    m[i][j] = 1;
else m[i][j] = 0;
```

or

```
m[i][j] = [pow(-1,i+j)+pow(-1,i*j)]/2;
```

It's easy to code it, but these conditions should be entered by the user. So i was thinking about storing all the input on a string and then interpreting it from there, i find it complicated though. Would you say this is a bad/non-viable solution?

Comment: So you're asking to run a compiler on the user's input? You may have better luck with python or similar.

Comment: It is complicated, depending on how many operations you want to support, but this is the right direction. Much easier is to have a small number of canned algorithms the user can pick from a menu. If they want something extra fancy, use excel, matlab, whatever to generate the numbers and feed the numbers to the program as a file.

Comment: You could make your own parser for the user inputted code.

Comment: You are trying to implement a simple programming language. You probably want to read a book about compilers and interpreters.

Comment: [Lua](https://www.lua.org) is a simple language that's explicitly designed to be easy to embed in other applications. I'd suggest you investigate it as it is fairly simple to embed into C++ applications and would let your users write custom functions in Lua that you then run inside your main C++ app.

Answer (score 0):

> thinking about storing all the input on a string and then interpreting it from there, i find it complicated though.

Instead of storing all the input on a string, why not display both options, then let the user to fill in the variable values ? Like this :

```
Your matrix fill options :

[A]

if (a <= b*i+c*j <= d )
    m[i][j] = 1;
else m[i][j] = 0;

[B]

m[i][j] = [pow(-1,i+j)+pow(-1,i*j)]/2;
```

then if the user choose 'A', ask them to feed the a,b,c,d values. Same goes for 'B'. You may add simple visuals too. ( :

> Would you say this is a bad/non-viable solution?

IMHO, bad is relative. If you want this code to be maintainable, don't forget to comment the code key points. If you are making this for an assignment with constrains attached.. it seems like your are doing it right.

In my personal view, 500 line of code that confidently works well, is MUCH better than 5 lines of codes that disturbing me deep inside. If you are clear on the planned algorithm to be executed, what's left is just coding it right, and improves/simplify the GUI wherever applicable.

Hope that helps.. ( :